# How to make sure all the procedures runs using redshift.sql, even if one individual procedure fails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have 3 procedures in a single procedure

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.a()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
call public.abc();
call public.abc1();
call public.abc2();
END;
$$;
```

How can I make sure all the procedures run even if one individual procedure fails.

I was trying to use try/catch, but redshift does not support the try/catch pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Redshift document has a good example explaining the way to handle this case

Please refer the following [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-trapping-errors.html)

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (firstname varchar, lastname varchar); 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Tomas','Smith'); 
CREATE TABLE employee_error_log (message varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_employee_sp_3() NONATOMIC AS
$$
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE employee SET firstname = 'Adam' WHERE lastname = 'Smith';
        EXECUTE 'select invalid1';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE INFO 'An exception occurred in the first block.';
        INSERT INTO employee_error_log VALUES ('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Edie','Robertson');
        EXECUTE 'select invalid2';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE INFO 'An exception occurred in the second block.';
        INSERT INTO employee_error_log VALUES ('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL update_employee_sp_3();
INFO:  An exception occurred in the first block.
INFO:  An exception occurred in the second block.
CALL

SELECT * from employee;

 firstname | lastname  
-----------+-----------
 Adam      | Smith
 Edie      | Robertson
(2 rows)

SELECT * from employee_error_log;

                     message                     
-------------------------------------------------
 Error message: column "invalid1" does not exist
 Error message: column "invalid2" does not exist
(2 rows)
```